# getting BAD_EXC_INSTRUCTION and Optional.None swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, viewcontroller

I'm now very confused.

I am trying to set a label in one viewController by inputting text into a textbox on a secondView controller and pressing a button. When I do this however, I get a Optional.None error while trying to set the label - but the text is passed back as I can println it just fine from the 1st viewController...

I'm just using "HI" for testing purposes (saves time).
I obviously left out a lot of code here - if there is anything else you need please say.

First View Controller:

```
@IBAction func btnOptions(sender : AnyObject) {
    var view: SecondViewController = SecondViewController()
    self.presentViewController(view, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func setLabel(text: String)
{
    println(text)
    lblTester.text = text
}
```

Second View Controller:

```
@IBAction func btnTester(sender : AnyObject) {
    var first: ViewController = ViewController()
    first.setLabel("HI")
    self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: Can you show how to set up your `lblTester`? My guess is, it is `nil`.

Comment: It is nil indeed. But surely if I try set the text it should change? In my viewDidLoad method it sets the text just fine (did that as a test)
`@IBOutlet var lblTester : UILabel = nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**lblTester** is an outlet so before view is loaded it is nil (an optional value) or you are not initialised it,  so you need to check for **lblTester** exist or not before setting value i.e

`func setLabel(text: String)
{
    println(text)
    if let label = lblTester {
    lblTester.text = text
    }
}`

Comment: Ah that gets rid of the error message - Thank you! For some reason I thought things would be initialized first before `setLabel` was called. 
I understand whats going on now. But, how would you set the label now? Seeing as functions all get run before anything is initialized...
I will be setting a few variables like this once I get it to work

Comment: You can have a separate model to store your value, while setting a value check isViewLoaded , if view is loaded set text value, when view about to appear set text value from model object.